# jquery show divs by default

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a page in which a query is run to see if a caller has forwarding enabled. The result page is a form that the user can use to make changes to his call forwarding if he chooses. the results from the query are either yes or no, and if yes, the forwarded to number. I am using jquery to hide the cfaDesc div if he selects the "disabled" radio button, that works great.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $("div.cfaDesc").hide();

   $("input[name$='cfa']").click(function() {
       var test = $(this).val();

       $("div.cfaDesc").hide();
       $("#" + test).slideDown('slow');
   });
 });
```

my problem is the initial query. If he has it enabled, I need to show the cfaDesc div. with the above query, no matter what the result is, it will be hidden. I am not sure how to change the hide/show attribute based on the query that is run before this code.

this was previous question that i inadvertantly marked as answered when it wasnt.  Here is my jfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/K3jrK/

Comment: "this was previous question that i inadvertantly marked as answered when it wasnt." Then there's no need to start a duplicate. Simply unaccept the answer from your other question.

Comment: oh thanks j, i didnt know you could unaccept answers.

Answer (score 0):

you're almost there. if you want the forward pane enabled by default, try this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $("div.cfaDesc").hide();

   $("input[name$='cfa']").click(function() {
       var test = $(this).val();

       $("div.cfaDesc").hide();
       $("#" + test).slideDown('slow');
   });
   $('#cfaEnabled').show(); // show the enabled div by default
});
```

new fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nmbE6/

Comment: Mike,  the problem here is my cfa radio button false is checked, this div still shows.  I need it to show if cfaEnabled, hide if false

Comment: ahh, i had it backwards. was hard to tell which checkbox was enabled or disabled because of the styling. give me a couple mins and i'll look at it again.

Comment: actually, going back and re-reading your question is just confusing me more. can you update your question to be a little more clear with exactly what is wrong and exactly what you want?

Comment: ok.  so i run a query to get whether has call forwarding turned on or off.  if he has call forwarding turned on, i want to show the div.cfaDesc (this will show what his number is forwarded to).  if it is off, i want to hide this div.   now.   this whole page is a form, so he can edit his settings.  thus the radio buttons.  if his fwd'ing is disabled, and he clicks the enabled radio button, i want to show the div.  if his fwd'ing is on, and he clicks disable, i want to hide the div.

Comment: ahh, i see. you're generating the page with server side code that does a query on the back end to see if this user has forwarding enabled?

Comment: yea.  so you login and, and i get your info. i generate the values of the radio button checked status based on query.  you have call forwarding enabled, and its forwarding to 12345.  I want to show this.  you want to turn forwarding off? you click disable, this should hide the div. and vice versa.

Comment: I have the query result in a php variable before i run the jquery.  if i could, i would put the php var in the jquery... (if $enabled == "true", show div)....make sense?

Comment: yeah, you are probably going to need to somehow insert a script block higher up in your page to just declare some bool variable that you can use in the jquery code you've posted. something like `<script type='text/javascript'>var ForwardingEnabled = true;</script>`. make sense?

Comment: yea, i think so....let me see what i can do.

Comment: just set the var to whatever the result of your query in php is, and then in the script you can say `if (ForwardingEnabled) { // never show the enabled div }`

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/2ThLV/   the problem is if the query result is true, this is always true, and this breaks the enable/disable hiding div portion.